# Saying "emes toraseinu ha'kedosha vehatehora"

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, torah-service

There is a minhag of the **tzibur** saying the above phrase while the one who is oleh la'Torah says the **second** brocho. 
This was the minhag of my father z"l who was born in Satmar. I have been asking people who say it and it appears that the minhag originates from the Satmar region - but NOT Satmar chassidus.
Does anyone know a possible source for this minhag and where it originally comes from?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28498&st=&pgnum=126&hilite=

Comment: I've seen Sfardim say "emet [torateinu hak'dosha]" *before* saying the second bracha when they get an aliyah. Just saying.

Comment: See https://jewishlink.news/features/36589-emet-toratenu-hakedosha and https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/908722/